# How to import products using csv file

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, category-products, cronjobs, custom-extension

I want to import all products from csv to my magento 1.9.x store so can anyone have idea so please share with me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magmi**
Using magmi tool you can easily import update products.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Magmi_Wiki

```
1.Copy magmi to your root directory and unzip it as (https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

2.Give permission 705 or 777 to this directory (sudo chmod 705 -R /var/www/html/magmi)

3.Browse to http://website.com/magmi/web/magmi.php

4.configure Global parameters as

    host localhost
    port 3306
    version of magento 1.9.x
    DB name yourDB name
    Username Yourusername & password
    Current profile Default
```

Comment: but I don't know how to configure and use this module so can you have any example for the same module?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: hey i am going to import csv but it will not show description same as csv's product description

Comment: check csv column name for description.

Comment: ok i can check again and know you if it's done or not

Comment: Thank you It's Working...